# how to return array in Node.js from module

Tags: javascript, node.js

getting undefined all the time "main.js":

```
var dbAccess = require('../dao/dbAccess');
dbaInstance = new dbAccess();
var wordPool = dbaInstance.getWordPool();
console.log (wordPool);
```

and "dbAccess.js" contains:

```
var DatabaseAccess = function() {}

DatabaseAccess.prototype.getWordPool = function () {
    RoundWord.find({},'words decoys', function(err, wordPoolFromDB) {
        if (err) throw err;
        //console.log(wordPoolFromDB); -working ok
        return (wordPoolFromDB);
    });
}

module.exports = DatabaseAccess;
```

why is it not working?

Comment: What is not working? any error?

Comment: "console.log (wordPool);" shows "undefined" instead of array

Comment: @V.Pud see updated answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

`DatabaseAccess.prototype.getWordPool` is not returning any result.

Since you are using an asynchronous function, you need do one of these things:

a) Take a callback as parameter and invoke the callback with a result

```
DatabaseAccess.prototype.getWordPool = function (cb) {
    RoundWord.find({}, 'words decoys', function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
           return cb(err, null);
        }

        cb(null, results);
    });
}
```

The callback convention is: `cb(error, results...)`

b) Use promises

```
DatabaseAccess.prototype.getWordPool = function () {
    return RoundWord.find({}, 'words decoys', function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            throw err; // however you might want to sanitize it
        }

        return results;
    });
}
```

To consume this result you will need to do it as a promise

```
databaseAccess.getWordPool()
.catch(function (err) {
    // process the error here
})
.then(function (results) {
    // something with results
});
```

Comment: What library are you using? mongoose?

Comment: yeah, it's mongoose odm

Comment: i added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the function is Asynchronous you need to pass a callback to `find` to get the result:

```
DatabaseAccess.prototype.getWordPool = function (callback) {
    RoundWord.find({},'words decoys', function(err, wordPoolFromDB) {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(err, wordPoolFromDB);
    });
}
```

and call it as follows in main:

```
dbaInstance.getWordPool(function (err, wordPool) {
    console.log (wordPool); 
   // wordPool is only available inside this scope,
   //unless assigned to another external variable
});

// cannot access wordPool here
```

Comment: is it work in sync? Because there is no callback in function. will it work for err condition?

Comment: thanks for reply, but that additional "return" returns something strange:)

Comment: @PrashantTapase Well i'd need to know what `Roundwood.find` does or returns. I assumed it synchronous because of how the code was written. like `Array.prototype.find`

Comment: @V.Pud what is this "strange" something?

Comment: @PrashantTapase In err condition, the func will throw err. Its up to OP to safeguard in a try catch and handle as appropraite.

Comment: ok, thanks but how can i operate variable "wordPool" in main
"dbaInstance.getWordPool(function () {
    console.log (wordPool);
});"

Comment: @V.Pud you can only use the `wordPool` variable inside the context of the `getWordPool` callback. This is how async programming works. If you post more code, I'll be able to show you next steps.

Comment: ok, thanks man, its tottaly new area for exploration for me, have to read about it

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you change to this:

```
var dbAccess = require('../dao/dbAccess');
dbaInstance = new dbAccess();
dbaInstance.getWordPool(function(wordPool){console.log (wordPool);});
```

And:

```
var DatabaseAccess = function() {}

DatabaseAccess.prototype.getWordPool = function (cb) {
    RoundWord.find({},'words decoys', function(err, wordPoolFromDB) {
        if (err) throw err;
        //console.log(wordPoolFromDB); -working ok
        cb(wordPoolFromDB);
    });
}

module.exports = DatabaseAccess;
```

Comment: can we write `var DatabaseAccess =  function (cb) { RoundWord.find({},'words decoys', function(err, wordPoolFromDB) {` with above code? What is roll of prototype in above code?

Comment: thanks for reply, but it isn't solution.  how can i operate "wordPool" in main.js? variable is still undefined

Comment: If you use asynchronous functions you have to consume the results in an asynchronous fashion. You can't mix synchronous and asynchronous code like that. You can operate on workPool inside the callback or use a blocking synchronous function to get the results but not both. sorry.